# Link against non-default glibc

Tags: c++, c, glibc

I'm trying to link [Andi Kleen's glibc implementation](https://github.com/andikleen/glibc) to enable lock-elision for a program with pthreads.
I link my program as follows:

```
g++ \
-Wl,--rpath=/path/glibc-elision/build/lib \
-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/glibc-elision/build/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
-o program program.o \
-fgnu-tm -mrtm -pthread \
-Wl,--no-as-needed --enable-lock-elision=yes
```

As long as I don't use any components of the libstdc++, everything works fine.

But as soon, as e.g. `std::vector` is referenced, the dynamic linker can't find the libstdc++.so.6 (`error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`).

To resolve this error, I tried to provide the custom as well as the standard glibc with `-Wl,--rpath=/path/glibc-elision/build/lib;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`.
This is not the correct call but the idea is to somehow provide both libraries.

So the question is:

**How to link a program against different components of two glibcs?**

I'm working on Ubuntu 13.10 with gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) 4.8.1.

Comment: This just sounds like your new ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 can't find the C++ runtime... As a quick check, you could try setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib64`.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the right approach: instead of the `libstdc++.so.6` error, I receive an error that `libgcc_s.so.1` could not be found (which indicates that `libstdc++.so.6` was found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Nemo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644691/link-against-multiple-glibcs?noredirect=1#comment36312821_23644691), the issue could be resolved by appending the C++ runtimes to the rpath. In my case, that is

```
-Wl,--rpath=/path/glibc-elision/build/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

The paths can be set by using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/path` as well.

It also turns out that I falsely used `;` instead of `:` to append the paths in the original post.